# C++ if, else if and else statement problems

Tags: c++, if-statement

In a short and basic testing C++ program I made the if, else if and else statement do not appear to be working. Regardless of what answer you input the if, else if and else statement just auto jumps straight to the else statement and I don't understand why. I have tried many different types of methods to remove this error but none appear to work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string name;
string feeling;
int age;

//IMPORTANT MESSAGE
cout << "THIS PROGRAM IS CAPS/SLANG SENSITIVE!" << endl << endl;
//IMPORTANT MESSAGE

cout << "Hello User, please enter name: ";
cin >> name;
cout << endl << endl;

cout << "Now please enter your age: ";
cin >> age;
cout << endl << endl;

cout << "Hello " << name << ", you are " << age << " years old." << endl << endl;
system("pause");
cout << endl;

cout << "How are you today " << name << "?: ";
cin >> feeling;
cout << endl << endl;

if (feeling == "Good")
cout << "That's great!";

else if (feeling == "Okay")
cout << "Fair enough.";

else;
cout << "Well to be fair I don't care so good day :)." << endl << endl;

cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your sample can be massively [reduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d01ff3393d2190e).

Comment: The correct answer has been given already, but have you considered what happens if someone's name consists of two parts, e.g. "John Doe"? Hint: use `std::getline` to read strings, not `std::cin >> s`.

Comment: You have syntax issue has you continue to write your codes. Once you know the flow of conditional statements such as IF & ELSE IF, you need to do encapsulation. In C++ you need open encapsulation "{" and closing encapsulation "}" every time you write a conditional statement, a function/method, define a class, write a for loop or a while statement. They just tell the compiler where the statement starts and where it ends, before it gets executed at run time.

Comment: Three upvotes for a typo.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because of the `;` after the `else`:

```
else;
```

That ends the statement too early, so the next line has nothing to do with the `if` conditions.

You should get into the habit of putting curly braces around your `if` blocks:

```
if (feeling == "Good") {
  cout << "That's great!";
} else if (feeling == "Okay") {
  cout << "Fair enough.";
} else {
  cout << "Well to be fair I don't care so good day :)." << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semi-colon after `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You put a semicolon `;` after `else`

remove that write like :

```
else
    cout << "Well to be fair I don't care so good day :)." << endl << endl;
```

Also You can use bracket to easily understand..